# nginx ingress controller 0.26.1 returns 504 (timeout while connecting to upstream) on GKE v1.14

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I recently upgraded my gke cluster to 1.14.x and nginx ingress to the latest version 0.26.1. At some point my ingresses stopped working.

For instance, when trying to access Nexus with `curl INGRESS_IP -H "host:nexus.myorg.com"`, these are the ingress controller logs:

```
2019/11/07 08:35:49 [error] 350#350: *2664 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.81.2.76, server: nexus.myorg.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.8.25.3:8081/", host: "nexus.myorg.com"
2019/11/07 08:35:54 [error] 350#350: *2664 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.81.2.76, server: nexus.myorg.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.8.25.3:8081/", host: "nexus.myorg.com"
2019/11/07 08:35:59 [error] 350#350: *2664 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.81.2.76, server: nexus.myorg.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.8.25.3:8081/", host: "nexus.myorg.com"
82.81.2.76 - - [07/Nov/2019:08:35:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 504 173 "-" "curl/7.64.1" 79 15.003 [some-namespace-nexus-service-8081] [] 10.8.25.3:8081, 10.8.25.3:8081, 10.8.25.3:8081 0, 0, 0 5.001, 5.001, 5.001 504, 504, 504 a03f13a3bfc943e44f2df3d82a6ecaa4
```

As you can see it tries to connect three times to 10.8.25.3:8081 which is the pod IP, timing out in all of them.

I've sh'ed into a pod and accessed the pod using that same IP with no problem: `curl 10.8.25.3:8081`. So the service is set up correctly.

This is my Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: some-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 30M
spec:
  rules:
  - host: nexus.myorg.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nexus-service
          servicePort: 8081
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot of fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem had to do with network policies. We have some policies to forbid the access to pods from other namespaces and allow only from the ingress namespace

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: NetworkPolicy
  metadata:
    name: allow-from-ingress-namespace
    namespace: some-namespace
  spec:
    ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            type: ingress
    podSelector: {}
    policyTypes:
    - Ingress

  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: NetworkPolicy
  metadata:
    name: deny-from-other-namespaces
    namespace: some-namespace
  spec:
    ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
    podSelector: {}
    policyTypes:
    - Ingress
```

With the upgrade we lost the label that is matched in the policy (type=ingress). Simply adding it fixed the problem: `kubectl label namespaces ingress-nginx type=ingress`